# WPF: How to create Multiple instances of a UserControl inside a for loop with different name?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-controls

I am creating a WPF window, inside which I am creating multiple instances of a UserControl.
I am using a for loop to create a new instances of the UserControl, how can I give different name to the UserControlinstance?
This is what I am doing:

```
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        MyUserControl <name> = new MyUserControl ();
        /*code to change the properties of usercontrol*/
        SomeStackPanel.Children.Add(<name>);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) property like this:

```
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            UserControl uc = new UserControl();
            uc.Name = "name"+i; // add your name here
            sp.Children.Add(uc);
        }
```

### EDIT

to answer your question in the comment how to get the Control

```
        var list = sp.Children.Cast<UserControl>();             // now we are able to use Linq
        var sublist = list.Where(item => item.Name == "name1"); // searching for all UserControl with the Name "name1"
        var uControl = sublist.FirstOrDefault();                // will result inyour UserControl or null

        //same as above just in one line
        var uControl2 = sp.Children.Cast<UserControl>().Where(item => item.Name == "name2").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi WiiMaxx,  When i tried this I did not get the instance of the Usercontrol in another function. I could not able to access the Usercontrol with the Name I updated in the second line.

Comment: The power of WPF is that it is not WinForms. Using WinForms-style code to create WPF will result in disaster.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak sure but he was was asking how to "solve" the problem based on his code. Sometimes you have to do such mistakes to learn from them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create your app in MVVM way don't use names and don't create user controls in your code.

Create instances of view model class instead, add them to collection and bind the collection to `ItemsControl` (or similar control) `ItemsSource` property. Change the item template to render your control.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <your:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `FrameworkElement.RegisterName` for your control to notify WPF that new named element was added.

```
//If you are creating stack panel in code you need to uncomment next line
//NameScope.SetNameScope(SomeStackPanel, new NameScope());

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl ();

    control.Name = "name" + i;

    SomeStackPanel.RegisterName(control.Name, control);
    SomeStackPanel.Children.Add(control);

}
```

You can read more about `RegisterName` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.registername.aspx).